# Nodejs - incorporate HTML files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm super new to NodeJS and I'm using it for a small college project.
The project itself is a Unity based game and as part of this project I need to build a small website for it.

I've created a few HTML files (homepage,about,download page,registration form).

I know I can use:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(3000);
```

But this just displays one line of text.

I would like to link all of these pages or set the homepage using Nodejs.
I've read about 'express' server and using static pages, but given that the website should allow the user to register/login, I doubt it qualifies as 'static' use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using an ```express``` server?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald
I have downloaded the express package, but I cannot figure out how to use it...

Comment: ok so you have generated an express application directory? after running ```npm install express-generator -g``` or something like this, from the command line @DavidFaiz

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald
Yes, I've read about that but yet to use it.
I have 3 static pages, but the website should allow the user to login and register and I'm not sure that login and register qualify as 'static'.

Comment: @DavidFaiz You are essentially asking how to build a whole website in NodeJS and that is a very open ended question. Am I correct to assume this or can you point out the specific area where you need help?

Comment: html pages are generally considered static ie - there content is the same every time they are loaded. Static doesn't mean they cant have functionality.

Comment: The great thing about express is that you can serve all your pages using [`express.static()`](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html) then expose APIs to handle login and registration (which the client pages could then consume via AJAX)

Comment: @DavidFaiz Please work through the tutorials on the expressjs homepage. Don't make us write a new tutorial just for you, that's not a nice thing to do.

Comment: @Tomalak
I finally managed to get it to work...thank you for the help.

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald
I was misusing

'app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));'

method.

Answer (score 0):

I was incorrectly using the express.static method...finally got it to work

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(80,"172.31.16.218");
console.log('Server running at http://172.31.16.218:80/');
```